# Divide long number by 10 or 100?

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have two strings and want to divide them. As I know, you can't divide strings, you first have to convert them into int, double, decimal, whatever. Now, my problem is the Length of the string is 1000 chars or more, so I can't use `int` (because the string is too long to fit in it). What can I do, when I want to divide a string with more than 1000 digits by 10 or 100?

Comment: Are you dividing by any number between `10` and `100` (so, it could be 22, 48, 92), or _only_ by 10 _or_ 100?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I use only 10 and 100.

Comment: Do you want the result still expressed as a string or do you want it to be a numeric value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use a type which supports numbers of arbitrary lengths, e.g. [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

However, as you want to divide by 10 or 100, the solution is much easier for decimal numbers. A division by 10 is nothing more than chopping off the last character; a division by 100 is chopping of the last two characters. So if your input is a string, you can just use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) to solve this:

```
string number = "124235235235"; // imagine a longer number here

// (integer) division by 10
Console.WriteLine(number.Substring(0, number.Length - 1)); // 12423523523

// (integer) division by 100
Console.WriteLine(number.Substring(0, number.Length - 2)); // 1242352352
```

If you want a [real](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) division, you would have to find the index of the decimal point, and move it one—or two—positions to the left:

```
string number = "123456.78901"; // imagine a longer number here
int i = number.IndexOf(".");

// division by 10
Console.WriteLine(number.Substring(0, i - 1) + "." + number.Substring(i - 1, 1) + number.Substring(i + 1)); // 12345.678901

// division by 100
Console.WriteLine(number.Substring(0, i - 2) + "." + number.Substring(i - 2, 1) + number.Substring(i + 1)); // 1234.5678901
```

Comment: The ToString() method supports a maximum of 50 significant digits in most cases; any digits beyond that become zero. If your BigInteger value may exceed 50 significant digits, use the ToString("R0") format rather than ToString("N0").

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.

From MSDN:

> The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an
>   arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower
>   bounds. The members of the BigInteger type closely parallel those of
>   other integral types (the Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, SByte, UInt16,
>   UInt32, and UInt64 types). This type differs from the other integral
>   types in the .NET Framework, which have a range indicated by their
>   MinValue and MaxValue properties.

You can try the below approach if you are satisfied with following 2 conditions:

**Note 1 :** if you want to divide it by only 10 or 100.
**Note 2:** if you want to have result as string

Try This: if you don't decimal points

```
string num = "12345";
int index= num.IndexOf('.');
if(index>0)
num = num.Substring(0, index);
string dividedBy10 = num.Substring(0,num.Length - 1);//gives you 1234
string dividedBy100 = num.Substring(0, num.Length - 2);//gives you 123
```

Try This: if you want decimal points.

```
string num = "12345";
int index= num.IndexOf('.');
if(index>0)
num = num.Substring(0,index);
string dividedBy10 = num.Insert(num.Length - 1, ".");//gives you 1234.5
string dividedBy100 = num.Insert(num.Length - 2, ".");//gives you 123.45
```

Comment: `num="123.45"`  `goto firstComment;`